# Actual nested layouts in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 layout files for what I am trying to do:

```
application.html.erb
show_layout.html.erb
```

The end goal being that for several Models, the show method will use this new layout.
Following the information on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts I figured it would look like this:
It would render the contents of the show file for the model, passing that to the `show_layout.html.erb` which will then pass that to the default `yield` in the `application.html.erb`
When I attempted to add `<%= render template: "layouts/application" %>` to the bottom of `show_layout.html.erb`, it was just adding the content above the contents in the default layout. Putting it below did the opposite.
I was able to figure out a solution by wrapping the entire `show_layout.html.erb` in a `<% content_for :override_yield do %>` and then adding `<%= yield :override_yield %>` in `application.html.erb` next to the default yield.
Unless I am thinking of this the complete wrong way, It seems like wanting to have a layout that overrides the default yield would be a common occurrence.
My question is, is there not a better way to achieve this?

Comment: i dont quite get your q but look at partials..  3.4 section there

Comment: I am using partials. The issue I have though is that I have a layout that will be used between the show pages for 14 models. Those show page use partials themselves. But I wanted to avoid needing to use the same partial (when it is only for layout) on every show page when I figured the layout would achieve what I wanted.